# Delete Mutiple Users from a Sharepoint Group

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-rest-api, user-accounts

Does anyone have insight as to how to delete multiple users from a SharePoint group?

Currently, I can only delete one user at a time via

```
REST POST: /users/removebyid()
```

Comment: Is REST a requirement? I think you could remove multiple via the JSOM object model.

Answer (score 1):

Rest API Id parameter not available to set with multiple values, a workaround is to get the UserCollection in the group firstly and then put the user id in an array, loop the array to get user id and remove.

A code snippet for your reference:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">  
   ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(RemoveMultipleUsers, 'sp.js');
var userids=[12,13];
function RemoveMultipleUsers()
{ 
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext("http://sp/sites/teams");
    var oWeb = clientContext.get_web()
    var collGroup = oWeb.get_siteGroups();

    var oGroup = collGroup.getById(7); //Change 7 based on the group's id
    var oUser = oGroup.get_users();
    console.log(oUser);
    clientContext.load(oUser);
    for(var i=0;i<userids.length;i++)
    {
       oUser.removeById(userids[i]);
    }
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed));

}
function onQuerySucceeded(){

    alert('User Removed');
}

function onQueryFailed() {
    alert('Failed');
}
```

Replace all the userid which want to remove in the userids array and also the site url and group id, it will work as expected.